# project-reactor - Nullpointer when loading UUIDUtils with a failsafe integration test

Tags: reactor, project-reactor

I am running into a NP when running an integration test of the reactor EventBus with failsafe

I think this this because the class UUIDUtils is being loaded by the bootstrap classloader and hence the call to getClassLoader() is returning null?

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at reactor.core.support.UUIDUtils.<clinit>(UUIDUtils.java:39)`

`IS_THREADLOCALRANDOM_AVAILABLE = null != UUIDUtils.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(
                    "java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom"
            );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you mind creating a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/issues) on this so we can track a fix? Sounds like maybe we just need to try/catch setting this boolean and let it be `false` in this case.

Comment: Jon - some additional information. This is a very specific use case. The reactor is shaded and on the bootclasspath (it is running in a Java agent). This is a situation unlikely for any general user as the classloader will normally not be null except if the class is loaded by the bootstrap classloader.

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight. I changed the catch clause to grab any `Throwable` where before it was only catching `ClassNotFoundException`. Hopefully this will allow it to not error out and use the default `Random`.